# multiple resultset php

Tags: php, mysql, resultset, procedure

I have a procedure which returns a multiple result set for following procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Proc1;

CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1()

BEGIN

  SELECT Column1
    FROM Table1

  SELECT Column2
    FROM Table2

END
```

How to write a PHP Code which takes records from both the select queries - Multiple Resultset

```
$Conn   = $this->new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbName');         

$strSQL = 'CALL Proc1()'; 

$stmt = $Conn->prepare($strSQL);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($Column1);

while($stmt->fetch())
{

  array_push($row, $Column1);

}
```

Now what should i do to get the Recordset from the second Mysql Select Query in the Procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using mysqli extension.

Have a look at these functions -

- [use_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php)
- [next_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php)